# Segue with no button help needed

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have checked previous queries all but they are different or too advanced for me. I have buttons done programatically so I need to segue using program as well. I am not sending anything, just to go to the next ViewController. Documentation said if not passing anything just use: `- (id)initWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier source:(UIViewController *)source destination:(UIViewController *)destination`. But I don't understand plus (+) or class yet. Also I cannot just put `gjRelaysViewController` as destination, Xcode says it is not declared. It is correct for me to create an instance? I have tried prepare for segue but nothing came out of it. Thanks.

Source: gjViewControllers

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIStoryboardSegue *relaysSegue;
@property (nonatomic, strong) gjRelaysViewController *relays;

[_pushButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(relayCircuitsOn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

 -(void)relayCircuitsOn: (id) sender
{
    _relaysSegue = [[UIStoryboardSegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"toRelays" source:self destination: _relays];
 }
```

Destination: gjRelaysViewController

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if(![segue.identifier isEqual: @"toRelays"])
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a storyboard with the segue on it already?

Comment: Yes Fogmeister, connected from gjViewController to gjRelaysViewControllers

Comment: Thanks ujeli for editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl-Drag in InterfaceBuilder from ViewController 1 to ViewController 2 to create a segue. Click on the segue and give it a name in the right pane.

In your code in `relayCircuitsOn` call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Insert the name you specified above" sender:self];
```

and you should be all set.

Alternatively you can do the transition in code:

1. Import ViewController 2 in ViewController1.m `#import "ViewController2.h"
2. Create a new instance of ViewController2: `ViewController2 *vc = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];`
3. Push it to the navigation stack (if you have one?): `[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];`

Comment: With performSegueWithIdentifier, it does not give error but it goes back to simulator's "home" view instead.

Comment: Check the segue in InterfaceBuilder, my guess is that it's pointing from the to the wrong view controller. Maybe you can post a screenshot in your question of that

Comment: Mate, i have checked that this should really work by creating blank view controllers. I cannot post a photo yet because of "reputation". In your experience, would there be much difference between code and using button? or would a lot of UIImageviews cause this?

Comment: There should be no difference between using code or interface builder segues. Not sure how a lot of UIImageViews would have an impact here ...